# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

MemberDetailedComponent

```
@ViewChild('memberTabs', { static: false }) memberTabs: TabsetComponent;
ngOnInit() {
    /* get thr routes tab parameter */
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      const selectTab = +params['tab'];
      console.log('queryparams:' + selectTab);
      this.memberTabs.tabs[selectTab > 0 ? selectTab : 0].active = true;
    });
}
```

```
selectTab(tabId: number) {
    this.memberTabs.tabs[tabId].active = true;
  }
```

In the routerlink

```
[routerLink]="['/members']"[queryParams]="{ tab: 3 }"
```

although **selectTab** reads the value, the console shows tabs undefined

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: please note the `memberTabs` is undefined in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. Use `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: everything else looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `{ static: false}` with `{ static: true }`.